# I need help setting up my Arduino Uno with the port

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-setup

I'm using a Windows computer, and if I recall correctly I installed the IDE using the installer, so I probably don't need to manually install the drivers. However, I can't figure out how to set up the serial port with the Arduino. For me under Tools, there's no "Serial Port" option but instead "Serial Monitor" and "Serial Plotter."

When I tried to upload my file, it failed. When I clicked Serial Plotter, it gave this error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.4 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Sketch uses 940 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for
local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM1": 
The system cannot find the file specified.

Problem uploading to board.  
See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
Board at COM1 is not available

This report would have more information with 
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

How am I supposed to resolve this?

Comment: Check the Hardware manager in Control panel that recognizes your arduino board connected.

Comment: Is it a genuine Arduino or a cheap clone from eBay or Amazon?

Comment: "under Tools, there's no "Serial Port" option". It's **Tools > Port**. Is that menu item disabled?

Comment: Yes, it's the only option under **Tools** that's grayed out and disabled for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related but my computer doesn't seem to see my Arduino although it's plugged in. If I go to the **Device Manager** it's not even there.

Comment: Before we can help you, you **must** answer my question.

Comment: Yes, I bought it from Adafruit and I am 100% it is **completely** legit.

Comment: If you don't believe me: https://imgur.com/a/fZjc5

Comment: You need to see it in the device manager. I don't have Windows 8 to test it on, but I think the Windows versions of the IDE ship with a device driver for it.

Comment: It's not a question of believing you - the cheap clones use a different USB chip and the solution to your problem would be completely different depending on if it's a genuine Arduino (CDC/ACM interface) or a cheap clone (CH340G interface). The latter requires special drivers not bundled with the IDE.  Since it is a CDC/ACM interface based one we can assume it's not the drivers if you installed the IDE properly. So it may be your USB cable (note: some cheap charger cables don't have data wires) - try a different USB cable, try a different USB port, and at a pinch, try a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by following the tutorial by Adafruit. I had to install it manually in order for it to work.

Comment: The idea behind answering your own question is that it could be helpful to others who are having the same problem. This answer does not provide enough details to be helpful. Please edit to improve it. What tutorial are you talking about? Add a link to it. But don't only rely on the link for your answer because if the link goes dead the information is lost. Add a description of what you mean by "install it manually".